# Lipschitz continuous function ( with delta epsilon )

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a question. I would like to know, every Lipschitz continuous function can be proved with delta-epsilon? ( If we know, that function Lipschitz continuous can we always prove it with delta epsilon?) If no, which function such functions? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every Lipschitz continuous function can be proved with delta-epsilon, since Lipschitz continuous is stronger than just continuous .Just use $\dekta=\epsilon/L